# c# pass class variable as paramater in method LINQ like?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

I have a class with a lot of different string values

I have a collection class holding these with some sorting functions. Currently i have lots of reproduced code for "GetListOfDifferentProducts" "GetListOfDifferentManufacturers" etc.

Is this possible? Or am i going about this the wrong way.

These are all simple foreach loops

```
        public List<string> GetListOfDifferentProducts()
    {
        List<string> listOfResults = new List<string>();
        foreach (Product prod in listOfProducts)
        {
            if (listOfResults.Contains(prod.Name.ToLower()) == false)
                listOfResults.Add(prod.Name.ToLower());
        }
        return listOfResults;
    }
```

I'd like to pass in a class variable (Like LINQ?)

```
    public List<string> GetListOfDifferentVariables(variableType)
    {
        List<string> listOfResults = new List<string>();
        foreach (Product prod in listOfProducts)
        {
            if (listOfResults.Contains(prod.variableType.ToLower()) == false)
                listOfResults.Add(prod.variableType.ToLower());
        }
        return listOfResults;
    }
```

example Usage:

```
ProductList.GetListOfDifferentVariables(o => o.Name);
```

Sample input (Variable string Name)

- Apple
- Apple
- Apple
- Pear
- Banana
- Banana

Output

- apple
- pear
- banana

mvc

```
    class Product
{
    public string Name;
    public string Manufacturer;
    public string Description;
    public string Location;
}
class ProductCollection
{
    List<Product> listOfProducts;

    public List<string> GetListOfDifferentProducts()
    {
        List<string> listOfResults = new List<string>();
        foreach (Product prod in listOfProducts)
        {
            if (listOfResults.Contains(prod.Name.ToLower()) == false)
                listOfResults.Add(prod.Name.ToLower());
        }
        return listOfResults;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those sample inputs.

Comment: Sure added some simple inputs and outputs for you. i'll write up a brief class overview of a product quickly.

Comment: @mjwills i feel stupid now! Thank you. I knew it would be LINQ related, but i didn't twig that i could just use the LINQ methods to achieve it without even a wrapper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the distinct set of names, consider:

```
listOfProducts.Select(z => z.Name.ToLower()).Distinct();
```

Similarly for variableType:

```
listOfProducts.Select(z => z.variableType.ToLower()).Distinct();
```

*This will avoid you needing to write explicit `GetListOfDifferentVariables` etc methods.*

If you **really** want those methods, try something like:

```
public List<string> GetDistinctNames()
{
    return GetDistinctProperties(product => product.Name.ToLower());
}


public List<string> GetDistinctProperties(Func<Product, string> evaluator)
{
    return listOfProducts.Select(evaluator).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

whereby `GetDistinctNames` passes in the particular field (i.e. `Name`) and manipulation (i.e. `ToLower`) it is interested in.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] tmp =
{
    "Apple",
    "Apple",
    "Apple",
    "Pear",
    "Banana",
    "Banana"
};

string[] tmp2 =
{
    "Pear",
    "Banana"
};

IEnumerable<string> uniqueList = tmp.Distinct(); // Removes doubles
IEnumerable<string> notInTmp2 = tmp.Distinct().Except(tmp2); // could be also interesting ;)

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", uniqueList));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", notInTmp2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create general method:

```
    public IEnumerable<T2> GetListOfDifferent<T1, T2>(Func<T1,T2> selector, IEnumerable<T1> inputs)
    {
        var result = inputs.Select(selector).Distinct();
        return result;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T2> GetListOfDifferent<T1, T2>(string propertyName, IEnumerable<T1> inputs)
    {
        var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "p1");
        var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExp, propertyName);
        var lamdaExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2>>(member, new[] { paramExp });
        var selector = lamdaExp.Compile();

        var result = GetListOfDifferent(selector, inputs);
        return result;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var result =GetListOfDifferent<Product,string>(product => product.Name, items)
```

or

```
 var result = GetListOfDifferent<Product,string>(nameof(Product.Name), items);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the Property name as a parameter then you can use Reflection.
You will need to slightly tweak your Product class to have public properties.

```
public class Product
{
    private string _name, _manufacturer;


    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
    public string Manufacturer
    {
        get
        {
            return _manufacturer;
        }
        set
        {
            _manufacturer = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can write your GetListOfDifferentVariables function as

```
public List<string> GetListOfDifferentVariables(string propertyName)
    {
        List<string> listOfResults = new List<string>();
        foreach (Product prod in listOfProducts)
        {
            string propertyValue = (string)prod.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(prod);
            if (listOfResults.Contains(propertyValue.ToLower()) == false)
                listOfResults.Add(propertyValue.ToLower());
        }
        return listOfResults.Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

you can call the function using the name of the property

```
var names = GetListOfDifferentVariables("Name");
var manufacturers = GetListOfDifferentVariables("Manufacturer");
```